# "X is me" or "X is myself"

Tags: reflexives

Which is correct?

> The English Stack Exchange user with the ID of 5481 is **me**.
>
> The English Stack Exchange user with the ID of 5481 is **myself**.

Comment: You would normally say *me*, but *myself* is certainly possible. Using *myself* implies a certain sense of unexpected revelation, akin to *"...is none other than myself!"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would say "The English Stack Exchange user with the ID of 5481 is me."

However, the more preferred to way to say this would be "I'm the English Stack Exchange user with the ID of 5481."

Answer (score -1):

I would put it, "I am English Stack Exchange user ID# 5481."  Or, "User ID# 5481 in the English Stack Exchange, is me."

Comment: -1 for the comma in the latter sentence. Unacceptable.

Comment: Rimmer, doesn't the comma clarify where the rather long title ends? It's a mirror of the first comma. I sweated over that comma :-) I can see how it might seem stilted though.